# Query WHERE clause with multiple OR read from file

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, bulk-load

I have a table with details of data transfers. One of the fields is an IP associated with the transfer. I need to develop a query which will get me a subset of the rows in the table matching one of 79 IP's. There are 608 distinct IP's in the table.

I have a file which has the required IP's separated by newlines. Is there a way to develop a query which reads this file to get the required rows instead of me manually entering each of the IP's separated by an `OR`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the text with IPs separated by newlines in the database or your client, this query would do the job:

Transform the list to an array, unnest it and join to the main table:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(your_list_of_ips, E'\n')) AS ip) sub
JOIN  data_transfers d USING (ip);
```

More about the used function in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

#### [SQL `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)

To import from a file directly, you could use `COPY`. The data file has to be on the same machine as Postgres and you need to be a database superuser for this.

This time we already have a single IP per row:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp(ip text);

COPY tmp FROM '/path/to/file';

SELECT *
FROM  tmp
JOIN  data_transfers d USING (ip);
```

#### [psql `\copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

If your file is on a different machine or if you do not have superuser privileges, use the (mostly) equivalent `\copy` of psql instead. To do it from the bash (like requested in the comment):

```
psql dbname

dbname=# \set ips `cat ips.txt`

dbname=# SELECT *
dbname-# FROM  (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(:'ips', E'\n')) AS ip) sub
dbname-# JOIN  data_transfers d USING (ip);
```

`\set` is the psql meta-command to set a variable - to the contents of a file in this case.
`ips.txt` being your file with IPs.
`:'ips'` is the syntax for single-quoted [SQL interpolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION).

- More details in the always useful manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html).
- Here is a [related case on pgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/87bocv1nhe.fsf@comcast.net#87bocv1nhe.fsf@comcast.net).

Comment: Thanks. The copy option does not work since it requires me to be superuser. Where would I run the first option? Because if I run it after connecting to the database using psql I get an error column "ip" specified in USING clause does not exist in right table. Is there a way to do this from the command line on the client using psql?

Comment: @shaun: I expanded on psql `\copy`.